# com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION stopped working

Tags: android, google-voice-search

I've been successfully using com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION in my Android app to handle Ok Google searches for over a year now. But, this stopped working a few days ago.

Now when I say "Ok Google search for something on MY_APP", the SEARCH_ACTION intent is no longer sent.

Anyone else having the same problem, or better yet know a solution?